Map MDC values into logs of Quarkus application
I am setting an MDC value in my code. I do not know how to map this MDC value into my logs.
Example RestEndpoint
@Path("/hello")
public class ExampleResource {

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExampleResource.class);

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello() {
        MDC.put("correlation_id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        log.info("Sample log from Get Method");
        return "Hello from Quarkus REST";
    }
}

Logging configuration
quarkus.log.level=INFO
quarkus.log.min-level=DEBUG
quarkus.log.category."org.example".level=DEBUG

quarkus.log.console.json=true
quarkus.log.console.enable=true
quarkus.log.console.json.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
quarkus.log.console.json.excluded-keys=sequence,loggerClassName,loggerName,level,threadName,threadId,ndc,hostName,processName,processId
quarkus.log.console.level=INFO

Dependency used:
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-logging-json</artifactId>
 </dependency>

Current output
{"timestamp":"2024-05-06 21:47:44","message":"Sample log from Get Method","mdc":{"correlation_id":"03842e41-6e97-4bbc-bf23-9088872acb74"}}

Expected Output
{"timestamp":"2024-05-06 21:47:44","message":"Sample log from Get Method","correlation_id":"03842e41-6e97-4bbc-bf23-9088872acb74"}

Can someone help on how to map mdc value for correlation id, into a separate field like here in expected output ?
Sample project can be cloned here https://github.com/angelfrend/quarkus-logging-demo.git
